# A bilinear map's rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a bilinear map $f$, does someone know the terms:

1. the rank of $f$,
2. $\left[f\right]_{E}$ where $E$ is some basis?

I tried to find those definitions online and didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ is a bilinear form on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and if $E = \{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $[f]_E$ is the matrix with entries
$$
 \left([f]_E\right)_{ij} := f(e_i,e_j).
$$
One can then define the rank of $f$ as the rank of the matrix $[f]_E$, where $E$ is *any* basis of $V$; as julien rightly points out, this is because if $F$ is any other basis, then $[f]_F = P^{T} [f]_E P$, where $P$ is the change of coordinates matrix from $F$ to $E$, so that $[f]_F$ and $[f]_E$ are congruent, and hence have the same rank.

Comment: May I add that the rank is well-defined as the matrix of $f$ in another basis is $P^T[f]_EP$ (which has the same rank as $[f]_E$) where $P$ is the invertible matrix that gives the change of basis?

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, julien!

Comment: No problem! Maybe it is too late for me, but I think it is $P^TAP$ (congruence) rather than $P^{-1}AP$ (similarity) after the change of basis. Note that $[f]_E$ is a Grammian matrix.

Comment: [d'oh] Yes, you're right; given that I absolutely never deal with straight-up congruence in my line of work, it completely escaped me...